# Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem on return from Ext.ComponentQuery.request()

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to set the only view in my app of xtype = feededitor to be the active item in my viewport. Currently the viewport has another view as the main view, in a card layout. Not sure why this code is not working, or I can't even extract getXTypes() from the variable returned by Ext.ComponentQuery.query()

```
homesc = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('feededitor')
[
Ext.apply.create.f
]
homesc.getXTypes()
TypeError: undefined is not a function
homesc
[
Ext.apply.create.f
]
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(homesc)
Ext.apply.create.f {doPreventPanning: function, doPreventZooming: function, doBlurInput: function, maximizeOnEvents: Array[2], items: Ext.apply.create.f…}
```

Comment: Read the docs for the return type of `query`.

Comment: Thanks , just saw it returns an array. Calling the function on [0] of the array worked. Many thanks

Comment: I don't get why you all mention Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem. Ext4.2.2 API shows there is no setActiveItem method. Are you talking another version? Trying to use this but no cigar for me... Grrrrrr